# Software to backup/restore Windows settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec

Wondering if there is a software to backup and then restore all Windows 7 native settings.

The use-case is that I've reinstalled my PC or want to replicate same settings on other PC without configuring one-by-one.

Note: please don't suggest built-in Easy Transfer Tool.

Comment: It might be helpful if you state what you don't like about Easy Transfer so nobody suggests anything with the same problems.

Comment: Well, I just want to selectively backup settings. In case of Easy Transfer I got 3.1Gb of garbage I'm sure and I certainly don't want to transfer all that garbage to my newely installed PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [User State Migration Tool 4.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd883247%28WS.10%29.aspx) a shot to see if it is better suited to your needs over Windows Easy Transfer. If it doesn't do what you need you can view a list of more alternatives at [AlternativeTo.com](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-easy-transfer/)